# Jquery wrap table tbody with a div

Tags: jquery

How do I wrap the table's tbody with a div?

myTable:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

my goal:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <div class="scrollbar"><tbody></tbody></div>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

I am using jquery plugin mcustomscrollbar to make sure the tbody part stick at 30% of the screen height when the data rows increase.

Comment: This is not valid HTML, why would you do that?

Comment: What is the objective behind your goal? [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: oh. I am sorry, I didnt know that. Basically the table might have 20rows or more  data. And I wanted to add a scrollbar to the tbody instead the whole page.

Comment: Browsers will render your invalid html not the way you expect. You should think of some other way to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh lol. kapantzak's comment upvote faster than eminem's rap. I guess I should remove this question.

Answer (score 4):

Whell if you really want to do this, then use wrap :

```
$('table > tbody').wrap('<div class="scrollbar"></div>')
```

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

But as mentioned before, you are creating a not valid HTML. I don't see the purpose for this, unless you are interested in some sort of scrolling table body. But for that I would recommend using some sort of jQuery library or css.

Answer (score 3):

As per your requirement you can do this with css only:

```
tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;/*apply your height for the tbody*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.scrollbar').html('<tbody></tbody>')
```

This will add tbody inside .scrollbar div .

Comment: $('.scrollbar').html('<tbody></tbody>')

Comment: Wrong way around - he wants an existibg `tbody` to be wrapped in a `div`.